# ¿Cómo actualizar el día de una fecha en SQL?

Tags: sql

estoy tratando de actualizar el día de un campo de tipo DATETIME en SQL lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE [PRUEBA].[dbo].[TABLA]
SET DATEPART(dd,FECHA_INSERT) = 27
```

tambien lo intenté con:

```
UPDATE [PRUEBA].[dbo].[TABLA]
SET DAY(FECHA_INSERT) = 27
```

Pero me da el error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: La sintaxis que estás usando está mal. ¿Cuál es el campo que quieres actualizar en TABLA? Como ves, tu UPDATE no lo especifica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que construir la fecha otra vez, el error es un error de sintaxis porque necesariamente debes indicar la columna a asignar el valor nuevo en tu caso `SET FECHA_INSERT` no puedes hacer esto `SET DATEPART(dd,FECHA_INSERT)` ni esto `SET DAY(FECHA_INSERT)` porque no son nombres de columnas en tu tabla.

```
UPDATE [PRUEBA].[dbo].[TABLA]
SET FECHA_INSERT = CAST(CAST(YEAR(FECHA_INSERT)*10000 + MONTH(FECHA_INSERT)*100 + 27 AS VARCHAR(255)) AS DATE)
```

Comment: ¿Para qué estáis haciendo esto **CAST(CAST(YEAR(FECHA_INSERT)*10000**? otra cosa no olvidéis el **Where**.

Comment: Estoy construyendo mi fecha para que quede de esta manera `20180913` y a eso hacerle un `CAST` a `DATE` el no indico que estuviera haciendo un `WHERE` en su consulta.

Comment: gracias Victor, funcionó muy bien!

Comment: De nada amigo éxitos con tus proyectos